# can't pass javascript in jsx (TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

this is my app.js file

[image]

this is my Pokemon.js file
[image]

This is the error I get
[image]

Can anyone help me? what's wrong with this? what are the changes I should make. Thanks

Comment: Please move the code from screenshots into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it run

```
function Pokecard(props){
   return (
      <span>{props.name}</span>
   )
}
```

I hope you get it.

Answer (score 2):

the `this` keyword is only used in class components.  Since your child `Pokecard` component is functional, you only need `props.name`

Comment: As a further description, this type of error occurs when you try to reference a property of an object that doesn't exist.  "cannot read property `props` of undefined means that it cannot read the property `props` of the object `this` because `this` is not defined.

Comment: this was helpful. although I have to pass props in function Pokemon

Comment: You can still pass the props, just don't use the `this` keyword when you're referencing them